# How to convert specific byte in a byte array to integer

Tags: java, type-conversion, integer, byte

I have a scenario where in based on a given String I need to return an integer value.
I am hashing String to a byte array . Now since my Integer range is 0-999 which can be represented by 2bytes, I am hoping to use last two bytes of the byte array to convert to integer . 
But I am not getting the correct result

I have tried using Byte buffer wrap method , defining offset as length-3 and defining the length as 2

```
ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes,bytes.length-3,2).getInt()
```

I am expecting an Integer data based on the last two bytes of the array but getting 
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.BufferUnderflowException

Comment: Why `length-3` and not `length-2`?

Comment: The last two bytes are at `length-2` and `length-1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`ByteBuffer#getInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#getInt()) reads `4` bytes starting at the current position, however your wrapped `ByteBuffer` has a remaining size (`limit - position`) of `2`, hence it throws a `BufferUnderflowException`. Instead, you should use [`ByteBuffer#getShort`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#getShort()), which can be stored in an `int`.

Comment: Good answer. A minor and off-topic nitpick: https://brians.wsu.edu/2016/05/19/hence-why/

Comment: @DodgyCodeException Thanks for the tip!